# Hide and add a Tab to a UITabbar

Tags: ios, tabs, uitabbar

I'm working on a Tabbed Application with one tab showing information about the current neighbourhood if the user is within this specific region. If the user leaves the area the tab should be removed, if he enters the region the tab should be added again to the TabBar.

I achieved to calculate if the user is inside or outside the area using CLLocation. But I fail to remove and add the Tab again afterwards:

**UITabBarController.m:**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    currentposition = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    [self userisincity];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self userisincity];
}


- (void)userisincity
{
    if ((currentposition.coordinate.longitude > 17.50) && (currentposition.coordinate.longitude < 17.70) &&  (currentposition.coordinate.latitude > 37.45) && (currentposition.coordinate.latitude < 37.65)){

        NSLog(@"inside city");
        //add tab

    } else {

        NSLog(@"outside city");

        //remove tab
        NSUInteger indexToRemove = 0;
        NSMutableArray *controllersToKeep = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.viewControllers];

        UIViewController *removedViewController = [controllersToKeep objectAtIndex:indexToRemove];

        [controllersToKeep removeObjectAtIndex:indexToRemove];

        NSLog(@"%@", controllersToKeep);

        [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:controllersToKeep animated:YES];
    }

}
```

The log shows if the user is inside or outside so the location part works properly. controllersToKeep has 4 entries first and one gets removed. But `setViewControllers` has no effect.

How can I add the Tab afterwards again? It's a ViewController done and linked using Storyboards right now.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line of code from:

```
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:controllersToKeep animated:YES];
```

to:

```
[self setViewControllers:controllersToKeep animated:YES];
```

since `self` is the `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 0):

this solution works so far:
i also had to update the name of the tabs after adding/removing one.

```
if ((currentposition.coordinate.longitude > XY) && (currentposition.coordinate.longitude < XY) &&  (currentposition.coordinate.latitude > XY) && (currentposition.coordinate.latitude < XY)){  
   //add view
   NSMutableArray *ViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.viewControllers];

   if (ViewControllers.count == 3) {
       UINavigationController *nextomeNavigationController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerID"];
       //set the name of your Storyboard containing the ViewController and the ID you gave to the ViewController here
       [ViewControllers insertObject:nextomeNavigationController atIndex:0];
       [self setViewControllers:ViewControllers animated:YES];
   }

} else {
   //remove view
   NSMutableArray *ViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.viewControllers];

   if (ViewControllers.count == 4) {
       [ViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
       [self setViewControllers:ViewControllers animated:YES];
   }
}
```